# Add Exception in CSS selector in nth-child

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="doc-container">
  <p>one</p>
  <h1>two<h1>
<ul></ul>
  <p>three</p>
<table></table>
  <span>four</span>
  <p>five<p>
  <h3>six</h3>
</div>
```

The elements inside the div will be dynamic of type and count. I need to blur the first five elements but also if the first five elements includes a ul or table it should not blur it and stop the blurring further

is there any way for this problem?

```
.document-container > *:nth-child(-n + 5) {
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
```

here is the css to blur the first five elements but i am not able to add exception.

I tried this:

```
.document-container > *:nth-child(-n + 5) {
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
.document-container ul {
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
.document-container table{
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
```

but not working

Comment: So, in the above example none of the element should be blured at all?

Comment: in the example the 5 elements are p h1 ul p table ..so it should blur only p and h1 and stop blurring from ul

Comment: Should reopen, only the half of the answer is inside other question. Please read carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `~` operator.

Basically, every element after an `ul` or a `table` inside the five first, I set the blur to 0.

```css
.document-container > :not(ul):not(table):nth-child(-n + 5){
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.document-container > ul:nth-child(-n + 5),
.document-container > ul:nth-child(-n + 5) ~ *:nth-child(-n + 5),
.document-container > table:nth-child(-n + 5),
.document-container > table:nth-child(-n + 5) ~ *:nth-child(-n + 5) {
    filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="document-container">
  <p>one</p>
  <h1>two</h1>
  <ul></ul>
  <p>three</p>
  <table></table>
  <span>four</span>
  <p>five<p>
  <h3>six</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```css
.document-container > *:nth-child(-n + 5) {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
.document-container > ul:nth-child(-n + 5),
.document-container > ul:nth-child(-n + 5) ~ *,
.document-container > table:nth-child(-n + 5),
.document-container > table:nth-child(-n + 5) ~ * {
  filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="document-container">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <h3>Heading 1</h3>
  <ul><li>List item</li></ul>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <table><tr><td>Table cell</td></tr></table>
  <span>Span item</span>
  <p>Paragraph 3<p>
  <h3>Heading 2</h3>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/oy8suwb1/).

> The general [sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (~) separates two selectors and matches
> all iterations of the second element, that are following the first
> element (though not necessarily immediately), and are children of the
> same parent element.

Answer (score -1):

```
.document-container > *:nth-child(-n + 5):not(ul):not(table) {
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Your Issues**
you forget to close your `h1` tag in line 3
and also close your `p` tag in line 8

if you want to blurred your text , also you can use this style

```css
.blur {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<p class="blur">Blurred Text</p>
```

`Read` it , `use` it , `vote` it and have happy Programming
Good Luck ;)